# For the quality of moderation, users should be able to thumb down moderators

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, moderators

Some moderators seem not qualified to moderate see
[Moderators are too trigger happy to close questions as off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60153/too-quick-moderation)

Users should be able to thumb them down and at some threshold their manager should review their behavior with them. Well may be there is no management, then they should lose points.

For avoiding retaliation tendancy, thumbdown will only be authorised by non-author of the post.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an issue with a moderator the best thing to do is to send a message to the team.  The Contact Us link at the bottom of each site links you to the address.

State your issue (civilly) and someone will get back with you.  I've done it before.  Works great.

**EDIT:**
To Chacha's comment, I still say send an email.  If you don't want to do that then flag one of your posts for moderator attention and they'll talk amongst themselves.  Jeff'll most likely still see it when flagged so you might as well just send an email where direct response with a trail is easier...

Comment: What if I think Jeff is the wrongdoer? Who do I talk to then?

Comment: @Chacha I don't think the comments are kept secret anyway, so it doesn't really matter either way; the ultimate goal is to change how things are done

Answer (score 2):

If you think a specific question was closed unnecessarily, you can do those thing :

- Edit your question to add explanation of why it shouldn't have been closed.
- Flag the question for moderator attention with a message explainning why you think it was badly moderated.
- Open a question here to discuss about it. If the question got closed and it shouldn't, you should be able to get it re-open fast. [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58359/request-to-re-open-a-question).

Let's consider that all the option above don't exist, what would it bring to down-vote a moderator ? In my own opinion, the moderator that would have the most down-vote would be the one that close the most subjective topic and the one that are the most active.

Let's consider that the down-vote metric is useful. Why would people down-vote a moderator ? Either because the decision was bad or because they are unhappy about it. In one case, the down-vote was used for what it's for and in the other case, it wasn't. It's not because people are unhappy about a decision, that is was a bad one, but they will still down-vote the moderator.

Overall, I think it's just a bad idea. It won't bring anything useful to the website.